# Making a button transparent Android?

Tags: android, button

How do I get rid of the white bit around the button? I don't want the button transparent, but I want the white bit around it. I've got Google Maps behind the button.

I've tried  android:background="@android:color/transparent", on the Button, but it's only the button that becomes transparent (not the white bit around it).

How do I do this in XML?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MyLocation" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="filterMenu"
            android:text="@string/filter_button" />
    </FrameLayout>

   <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this the complete XML? If not post the whole thing..

Comment: The whole XML is on now.

Comment: that's not a correct XML.

Comment: Set your framelayout background as transparent

Comment: I have and the button remains the same. thanks.

Comment: Please post the full XML. The above is in-complete / wrong.

Comment: Do you have these inside a Linear layout? If so set background transparent for the linear layout

Comment: Amulya, this is the full XML for this button. I'm viewing Google Maps API with a button on top of it. Thanks for replying Rani, and I have set the background transparent for linear layout, but the white still remains around the button.

Comment: I tried your code and it doesnt give me the white background. Weird!!

Comment: What color do you wish the background to be? You can't keep setting views transparent until you reach something in the hierarchy with a color that you can't access (white in this case). I believe you want to have to button overlain on your map, in that case you need to use a relative layout so that the view can overlap. Otherwise, take a look at the Pixel Perfect view and/or the Hierarchy Viewer...

Comment: Hi Tonithy, thanks for replying. I THINK I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the background of `RelativeLayout` to transparent?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="filterMenu"
            android:text="@string/filter_button"
            />
        <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And why not using `FrameLayout` anyway? It's better in performance than `RelativeLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="filterMenu"
            android:text="@string/filter_button"
            />
        <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, the button is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

MybuttonName.getBackground().setAlpha(0);

0= Completely transparent.
255 Completely opaque.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
Button filter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter);
filter.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```